# How to get hidden field value in aspx C# code (striplet) in ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0. 
I have one hidden field on .aspx page which stores a value which get generated automatically.

I am writing one more C# code on same aspx page to implement my logic.
How can I fetch that hidden field value on same page?

Code written on .aspx page  is as follows:

```
<div>
<%= Html.Hidden("MyHiddenField",SomeRandomLogic)%>    
</div>


<%  
string TokenGenerated = (Here I want the value of Hidden field MyHiddenField) 
%>
```

In above code, I want my Hidden field value in TokenGenerated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way by using `Request.Form`

```
<%  
string TokenGenerated = Request.Form["MyHiddenField"].ToString();
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the value of Hidden Field after submission or from the same page where you are using the hidden filed (current page).

If You want them After the submit then

```
Request.Form["MyHiddenField"].ToString();
```

but remember that hidden filed must be inside the form that which you are submitting.

if you want them from the current page then define the variable globally and define them value from the code and later retrieve it.

see this for example https://gist.github.com/anirugu/3e5ec01bb08585c570a5

Answer (score -2):

for that you can use like

```
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SortExpression)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SortDir)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PageNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but your solution will not work for me.
I think u get confused in my question. I will simplify and wil tell u.


I am assigning value to hidden field which is generated using some random number logic.
Now i want to access same value on same aspx page.

Comment: What is this? This answer was does not helps to OP question